# How to start script(.cmd) with WMI in C# code?

Tags: c#, wmi

I was trying to call a .cmd file remotely thru WMI in C# with code below:

```
ObjectGetOptions objectGetOptions = new ObjectGetOptions();
ManagementPath managementPath = new ManagementPath("Win32_Process");
ManagementClass processClass = new ManagementClass
            (manScope, managementPath, objectGetOptions);
ManagementBaseObject inParams = processClass.GetMethodParameters("Create");
        inParams["CommandLine"] = @"C:\temp\text.cmd";
```

Above code returned no error, it even got process ID with outParams["processId"]
However, it didn't do anything at remote server.  I then tried calling a vbs script with same procedure and it worked just fine.  So my question is, what is the proper way to call a .cmd file through WMI?  For vbs, I knew I should include the CScript command.  But how about .CMD file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should try running "cmd.exe /c c:\temp\text.cmd".
I think you need to invoke the command processor to make it work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I did follow your suggestion but the script still didn't do anything.  However, after I put the file into Windows/system32 without specify file location in code, it finally works!  

I did try to set the inParams["CurrentDirectory"] to somewhere else, but it just not working.

Comment: Got this all work out.  
With the suggestion above plus the "CurrentDirectory" setting and now it works!

Thanks for your help, Palle.